# Redux (w/ immer) state not updating on action

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, immer.js

I'm new to redux  and trying to get an action to produce a simple state update and component rerender in a new reactboilerplate project (that uses immer). Component to action is functioning correctly as confirmed by `console.log`, and I'm not passing any data, just an action that changes a `boolean`.

`homeVisible` should change from `false` to `true` in state.

Reducer:

```
import produce from 'immer';
import { SET_HOME_VISIBLE } from './constants';

// The initial state of the App
export const initialState = {
  homeVisible: false
};

/* eslint-disable default-case, no-param-reassign */
const homeReducer = (state = initialState, action) =>
  produce(state, draft => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case SET_HOME_VISIBLE:
        draft.homeVisible = true;
        break;
    }
  });

export default homeReducer;
```

Selectors:

```
/**
 * Homepage selectors
 */

import { createSelector } from 'reselect';
import { initialState } from './reducer';

const selectHome = state => state.home || initialState;

const setHomeVisible = state => state.homeVisible || initialState;

  const makeHomeVisible = () =>
  createSelector(
    setHomeVisible,
    homeVisibleState => homeVisibleState.homeVisible,
  );

export { selectHome, makeHomeVisible, setHomeVisible };
```

Actions (for continuity):

```
import { SET_HOME_VISIBLE } from './constants';

/**
 * Changes the input field of the form
 *
 * @param  {string} username The new text of the input field
 *
 * @return {object} An action object with a type of CHANGE_USERNAME
 */


export function setHomeVisible(homeVisible) {
  return {
    type: SET_HOME_VISIBLE,
    homeVisible
  };
}
```

Comment: in the reducer you have to return a value not set it

Comment: i do not see any examples of returning code within immers produce function within reactboilerplate. can you provide an example?

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't see the `immer` produce there. I haven't use immer in the reducers, so I cannot help you with this.

Comment: https://immerjs.github.io/immer/docs/example-reducer

Comment: im not seeing an issue here via that example, am i missing something?

Comment: your reducer doesn't seem to return (modified) state

Comment: i cannot find an example of immers produce function using return in the docs or in the reactboilerplate, can you provide an example?